# Android: file extension is undefined in the response body after uploading a file to server

Tags: android, file-upload

I am using the following code for sending files (pdf,docx,pptx etc) from user to user in a chatting application.

```
public class UploadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        protected MessageModel mMessage;
        File file ;
        String mimeType = "";
        public UploadFile(MessageModel msg, File file) {
            super();
            this.mMessage = msg;
            this.file = file;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            String responseBodyText = null;
            mimeType = mMessage.getMsgFileType();
            MediaType MEDIA_TYPE = okhttp3.MediaType.parse(mimeType);

            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            try {

        RequestBody req = new okhttp3.MultipartBody.Builder()
                        .setType(okhttp3.MultipartBody.FORM)
                        .addFormDataPart("chatFileUpload", file.getName(), RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE, file)).build();

                Request request = new Request.Builder()

                        .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+Constants.AUTH_TOKEN)
                        .addHeader("User-Agent", Constants.USER_AGENT)
                        .url(urlforFileUpload)
                        .post(req)
                        .build();


                Response response = null;
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();

                if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                    throw new IOException("Okhttp Error: " + response);

                } else {
                    responseBodyText = response.body().string();
                    Log.d("PrintResponseBody", responseBodyText); // Print the response body here
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

            return responseBodyText;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            JSONObject msgFiles = new JSONObject();
            if (result != null) {
                try {
                    JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(result);
                    msgFiles.put("filename", responseObject.get("fileName"));
                    msgFiles.put("mimetype", responseObject.get("mimetype"));
                    msgFiles.put("filepath", responseObject.get("fileUploadPath"));

                    Log.d("PrintFileUploadPath", String.valueOf(responseObject.get("fileUploadPath")));
                    // Print the response upload file path with file name and extension;

                    //.... do other stuffs....

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }
    }
```

In the logcat, I'm getting extension as 'undefined' instead of proper extension name (.docx, .pptx etc). Can someone tell me which might cause this kind of behavior? Is it appropriate? If yes, how am I supposed to check which type of file user is receiving from server response?

An example of response I'm getting using debugger:

```
{
"status":"true",
"fileName":"1490691261587.undefined",
"fileUploadPath":"/uploads/chat_upload/1490691261587.undefined",
"mimetype":"file/file",
"msg":"File is uploaded successfully",
"downloadLink":"<a  target=\"_blank\" href=\"/uploads/chat_upload/1490691261587.undefined\">New-Text-Document.txt909.txt</a>"
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your `else` part you have, `responseBody = response.body().string();`. But I suppose, it should be `responseBodyText = response.body().string();`. Is it just a typing mistake? Also, where do you print the extension?

Comment: Your post does not make sense. You are uploading a file. So why would there be another file in the server response? Why would you think there would be filename, mimeType and fileUploadPath in the response? You used them while uploading your file. Moreover there is indeed no extension code in your post.

Comment: `which type of file user is receiving from server response?`. The user is sending a file. Not receiving. Isnt it?

Comment: Yes, that was a typing mistake :( I am printing the extension in this line <b>Log.d("PrintFileUploadPath", String.valueOf(responseObject.get("fileUploadPath")));
                    </b>. Please check the edited post @PrerakSola

Comment: I am supposed to get a server response after file uploading. I have given a sample response, please check the post again. @greenapps

Comment: The issue is in your server side code. It is not setting the file name correctly. Post the server side code that sends the response.

Comment: The response is okay with correct file extension if I'm uploading file using postman :( @PrerakSola

Comment: `Thanks in advance.`. Well if you consider it done. Ok.